# How to set MQ headers using JSR223 sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq

I am working on IBM MQ testing. I able to inject my payloads request in MQ destination. I need to put the headers values in MQ to get the correct response. I used various option but still i am unable to put headers values in MQ server. Kindly let me know how can i solve this in JMeter.

Option 1 :

```
sendmsg = new MQMessage();
sendmsg.setStringProperty("QueryName", "GetPortfolio");
sendmsg.setStringProperty("Country", "LV");
```

Option 2:

```
rfh2.setFieldValue('usr', 'QueryName=', 'GetPortfolio')
```

Option 3:

```
SampleResult.setRequestHeaders("QueryName=GetPortfolio")
```

Answer (score 0):

Option # 1 is the correct way of doing it.

Option # 2 could be used but why?  And the parameter should not include the equals sign ( i.e. "=").

I have no idea what option # 3 is.

Here is a sample Java/MQ program that puts a message on a queue with named properties .

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

/**
 * Program Name
 *  MQTest11P
 *
 * Description
 *  This java class will connect to a remote queue manager with the
 *  MQ setting stored in a HashTable and put a message on a queue.
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *  -m MQA1 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c TEST.CHL -q TEST.Q1 -u UserID -x Password
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 */
public class MQTest11P
{
   private static final SimpleDateFormat  LOGGER_TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

   private Hashtable<String,String> params;
   private Hashtable<String,Object> mqht;
   private String qMgrName;
   private String outputQName;

   /**
    * The constructor
    */
   public MQTest11P()
   {
      super();
      params = new Hashtable<String,String>();
      mqht = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      boolean b = params.containsKey("-h") && params.containsKey("-p") &&
                  params.containsKey("-c") && params.containsKey("-m") &&
                  params.containsKey("-q") &&
                  params.containsKey("-u") && params.containsKey("-x");
      if (b)
      {
         try
         {
            Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            b = false;
         }
      }

      return b;
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ HashTable.
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      int port = 1414;
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (allParamsPresent())
      {
         qMgrName = (String) params.get("-m");
         outputQName = (String) params.get("-q");

         try
         {
            port = Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            port = 1414;
         }
         
         mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, params.get("-c"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, params.get("-h"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(port));
         mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, params.get("-u"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, params.get("-x"));

         // I don't want to see MQ exceptions at the console.
         MQException.log = null;
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Connect, open queue, write a message, close queue and disconnect.
    *
    */
   private void testSend()
   {
      MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
      MQQueue queue = null;
      String msgData = "This is a test message from MQTest11P";
      int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();

      try
      {
         qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht);
         MQTest11P.logger("successfully connected to "+ qMgrName);

         queue = qMgr.accessQueue(outputQName, openOptions);
         MQTest11P.logger("successfully opened "+ outputQName);

         // Define a simple MQ message, and write some text
         MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
         sendmsg.format = CMQC.MQFMT_STRING;
         sendmsg.feedback = CMQC.MQFB_NONE;
         sendmsg.messageType = CMQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
         sendmsg.messageId = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;
         sendmsg.correlationId = CMQC.MQCI_NONE;

         // Write message data
         sendmsg.writeString(msgData);

         /**
          * Set named properties aka message properties
          * that will create a JMS message.
          */
//         sendmsg.setStringProperty("mcd.Msd", "jms_text");
//         sendmsg.setStringProperty("jms.Dst", "queue:///"+outputQName);
//         sendmsg.setStringProperty("jms.Pri", "0");
         sendmsg.setStringProperty("QueryName", "GetPortfolio");
         sendmsg.setStringProperty("Country", "LV");

         // put the message on the queue
         queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
         MQTest11P.logger("Message Data>>>" + msgData);
      }
      catch (MQException e)
      {
         MQTest11P.logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         MQTest11P.logger("IOException:" +e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if (queue != null)
            {
               queue.close();
               MQTest11P.logger("closed: "+ outputQName);
            }
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            MQTest11P.logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
         try
         {
            if (qMgr != null)
            {
               qMgr.disconnect();
               MQTest11P.logger("disconnected from "+ qMgrName);
            }
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            MQTest11P.logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * A simple logger method
    * @param data
    */
   public static void logger(String data)
   {
      String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();

      // Remove the package info.
      if ( (className != null) && (className.lastIndexOf('.') != -1) )
         className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.')+1);

      System.out.println(LOGGER_TIMESTAMP.format(new Date())+" "+className+": "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()+": "+data);
   }

   /**
    * main line
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MQTest11P write = new MQTest11P();

      try
      {
         write.init(args);
         write.testSend();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         MQTest11P.logger("Usage: java MQTest11P -m QueueManagerName -h host -p port -c channel -q QueueName -u UserID -x Password");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

When I look at the message in the queue with [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html), I see:

[image]

[image]

So, your 2 named properties are with the message.

The question becomes do you want JUST named properties attached to the message or are you really looking to create a JMS message with named properties?

Note: A JMS message is internally defined as an MQRFH2 message.  i.e. JMS message ==> MQRFH2 message but the opposite may not be true.

Hence, if you want a JMS message with named properties then you need to uncomment those 3 lines in MQTest11P.java above.

i.e.

```
sendmsg.setStringProperty("mcd.Msd", "jms_text");
sendmsg.setStringProperty("jms.Dst", "queue:///"+outputQName);
sendmsg.setStringProperty("jms.Pri", "0");
```

Comment: Hi @Roger, Thanks for your answer. i am looking to put my payload message(XML) along with these 2 named properties. I have following details with me quemgrname, queuename, channelname, hostname, port, xml payload, 2 JMS properties that i have mentioned above.

Comment: Also is it possible to put queue manager details in script itself instead of command prompt in your code.

Comment: The code (MQTest11P.java) above shows you how to use QMgrName, Q name, hostname, etc.  Now if you are talking about JMeter then I can't help you because I have never used JMeter.